# AP Calculus Practice Tests

Tags: reference-request, education, book-recommendation

What are some good books to practice for the upcoming Calculus BC exam?

I don't want informative books, such as "How to get a 5" or such, but I just need practice tests, which I can do each day of spring break. Are there any books or online sources where I can find lots of mock tests, full with multiple choice free response scaled to time etc?

Comment: I actually burned through all of those during the february break @Moo

Comment: I don't know where you live, but you could go to the Barnes & Nobles and purchase a BC book from there. One time investment but worth it. Then when you hopefully get your "5" you donate it to your high school or gift it as a birthday present for your little brother/sister.

Comment: There used to be all the recent past free response tests archived at the AP web site. At least, I downloaded .pdf files for the AB and BC tests (free response only, but also has solutions with ruberics used) for late 1990s through about 2008 or so back around 2009 or 2010 for use with people I was tutoring back then. I